# Probability of waiting

Tags: probability

In a hospital, the waiting time for an elevator varies uniformly between 0 and 4 minutes. What is the probability of waiting more than 1 minute?

(a) 0.25
(b) 0.5
(c) 0.8
(d) 0.75
(e) 0.67

I feel like it is d, but I don't know.

Comment: Your intuition is correct.  Uniform distribution on an interval $[a,b]$ means,by definition, that the probability of landing in a subinterval $[c,d]$ is $\frac {|d-c|}{|b-a|}$.  In your case $$P(X≥1)=P(X\in [1,4])=\frac {|4-1|}{|4-0|}=\frac 34$$

Answer (score 0):

$$p\{X\geq 1\}=\frac{1}{4}\int_1^4dx=\frac{3}{4} $$